# I don't understand how Python 3 exec works

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, python-exec

```py
def beat():
    exec('nDns=1', locals())
    print(nDns)

beat()
```

Result `NameError: name 'nDns' is not defined`. When I change `locals()` to `globals()` it works, but I don't really want it written to globals. It must stay in scope of the function. How?

Comment: Short version: `locals()` returns a *view* of the existing locals (actually in an array in CPython), but you can't *create/modify* locals by modifying it (because local variables are determined statically when the function is compiled, and it can't detect arbitrary assignments to `dict`s, `eval` or `exec` based additions to locals). [Per the `locals` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals): "Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter. "

Comment: @ShadowRanger So what is the solution?

Comment: The duplicate offers options. But frankly, there is no way to *truly* dynamically assign to a local, and thinking you need to do so indicates [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040); you need to find a different design.